# angular4 html changes dynamically according to some variables

Tags: angular

HTML file:

```
<div [hidden]="isshow">
  <h1>this is a</h1>
</div>
<div [hidden]="!isshow">
 <h1>this is b</h1>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
  public get isshow() {
    return (this._state === 'ready');
  }
```

The state value is changed by an EventListener, and will change from "connecting" to "ready".

What I want is to show "this is a" at the beginning then change to "this is b" 
 when state is "ready", but looks it doesn't work.
*ngIf doesn't work either.
What should I do? Subscribe it?

If using a timer,the page will change, such as :

```js
setTimeout(()=>{this._state = 'ready'},30000);
```

But I don't want to use Timer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there is a small mistake in your code. if isshow is a function then you should pass it with brackets as mentioned below.

**template**

```
<div [hidden]="isshow()">
      <h1>this is a</h1>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!isshow()">
     <h1>this is b</h1>
    </div>
```

**component**

```
isshow() {
    return (this._state === 'ready');
  }
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iGKMboJ6sReHNGVCipNY?p=preview)

I hope this will help you. If you have any doubts or suggestions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

it's often better to toggle an element's presence using `*ngIf`.

```
  <div *ngIf="isshow()">
      <h1>this is a</h1>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!isshow()">
     <h1>this is b</h1>
    </div>
```